# C strcpy array of string pointers

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy

I have an array declared like so:

```
char *array[4];
```

which is populated by a different function with strings, i.e. ["one", "two", "three", "four"].

My goal is to copy this array into a new array, excluding the last two elements, so new_array would contain ["one", "two"].

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int *new_array[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    strncpy(new_array[i], array[i], strlen(array[i]));
}
```

But have received the following warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strncpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
```

extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,

Comment: `int *new_array[2];` => `char *new_array[2];`. And `strncpy` won't null terminate, and you have to use `strdup` instead.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake... thank you.  If you want to add an answer I'll accept it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your code

First it declares an array of integer pointers (hence the warnings) then those pointers aren't initialized. `strncpy` isn't the proper function to call (and even if the memory was initialized, it wouldn't null-terminate your strings), you need `strdup` which does the proper allocation & copy:

```
char *new_array[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    new_array[i] = strdup(array[i]);
}
```

(on some old systems, `strdup` may not be available. If you're in that case, just use `new_array[i] = malloc(strlen(array[i]+1));` then `strcpy(new_array[i],array[i]);`)

Both methods allocate dynamic memory and need `free` when not used anymore.

But if you just want to store the pointers, for instance because `array` contains *literals* and you're not planning to modify your strings, you could just copy the pointer:

```
new_array[i] = array[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

The source and destination are not compatible.
char *array[4];
int *new_array[2];

I hope you put int by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the wonderful answer given by Jean-François Fabre, I would point out that even a known size can change as a program evolves, for this reason it is useful to end lists with a known terminator (i.e. NULL or NaN).

I assume you're just beginning with C, but it's a good habit to get in to (the habit of seeking everything as transient and minimizing pre-conceptions in your code).

Although people point out that `strdup` isn't standard C, it is widely available. I will avoid it just for kicks. I hope you notice the error checks (excessive? maybe... but real code should be filled with these things).

Consider the following code (but don't use it, it might be slightly broken ):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **string_array_dup(char *const *ary) {
  int count = 0;
  char **copy;
  if (!ary)
    return NULL;
  /* count string items - this is unsafe */
  while (ary[count++])
    ;
  if (!count)
      return NULL;
  /* allocate memory for array and set terminator. */
  copy = malloc(sizeof(*copy) * (count + 1));
  if (!copy)
    perror("ERROR"), exit(errno);
  copy[count - 1] = NULL;
  /* itterate over array, allocate and copy strings. */
  count = 0;
  while (ary[count]) {
    int register len = (int)strlen(ary[count]);
    copy[count] = malloc(len + 1); /* remember NUL byte */
    if (!ary[count])
      perror("ERROR"), exit(errno);
    memcpy(copy[count], ary[count], len + 1); /* copy NUL byte */
    count += 1;
  }
  return copy;
}

void string_array_print(char **ary) {
  int count = 0;
  while (ary[count]) {
    printf("%s ", ary[count++]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void string_array_free(char **ary) {
  int count = 0;
  /* free each string */
  while (ary[count]) {
    free(ary[count++]);
  }
  /* free container */
  free(ary);
}

int main(void) {
  char *array[] = {
      "String", "array", "is", "always", "terminated", "with", NULL,
  };
  char **copy = string_array_dup(array);
  if (!copy)
    perror("ERROR"), exit(errno);
  string_array_print(copy);
  string_array_free(copy);
  return 0;
}
```

By the way, this code could be optimized to use only a single `malloc` (or using `realloc`) and a single `free` - at the cost of a more complicated copy process (and improving locality of the data and data access times).